# Unable to use the spread operator after ejecting create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app

I used create-react-app to create a react application.

After I run eject, I am unable to use the spread operator as follows:

```
//eslint-disable-next-line 
const { children, ...attributes } = this.props; //Line 19
```

It keeps giving me this error when I run yarn start

> Line 19:  Parsing error: Unexpected token ..

Webpack Dev Server
I have tried adding all the presets and the transform plugin to both webpack dev server config and .babelrc but no luck

```
// Process JS with Babel.
          {
            test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
            include: paths.appSrc,
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),    


            options: {
              presets:['react','es2015','env',"stage-2"],
              plugins: ["transform-object-rest-spread"],
              // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
              // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
              // directory for faster rebuilds.
              cacheDirectory: true,
            },
          },
          // "postcss" loader app
```

And in the babel rc file as well
    //.babelrc

```
{
    "presets":["env","react","stage-2"],
    "plugins": [
      ["transform-object-rest-spread", { "useBuiltIns": true }]
    ]
  }
```

It works fine if I don't eject the script.

Comment: Does not directly relate to your issue, but may point you in the direction you need. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3197

Comment: So the problem turned out to be eslint. Webpack was loading it before babel and while babel didn't have a problem with the spread, eslint did.

Answer (score 2):

So the problem turned out to be eslint.
Webpack config was loading it before babel

Adding parser options fixed it.

```
{
        test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: [
          {
            options: {
              formatter: eslintFormatter,
              eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
              "extends": "airbnb",
              "parserOptions":{
                "ecmaFeatures": {
                  "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
                }
              }

            },
            loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
          },
        ],
        include: paths.appSrc,
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated the @babel with this:
npm install @babel/runtime@latest did the work